# How can all commands be removed

Tags: node.js, vorpal.js

In the command.remove() example I can find and remove one command.

Eg.

```
const all = vorpal.find('*');
for (var cmd of all) {
  cmd.remove();
}
```

Is there an official way to remove all commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple enough that there doesn't really need to be an API method for it.

All commands are exposed through `vorpal.commands`. So:

```
vorpal.commands.forEach(function (cmd) {
  cmd.remove();
});
```

That should work.